how to create the infinity scroll in the angular without the memory leaks
I'm creating infinite scrolling in an Angular app to load data as the user scrolls in the application. I'm using RxJS to handle the data stream and ngx-infinite-scroll for the scroll events. However, I’m running into issues with memory management. As I scroll through pages, it seems like old data isn't being released, causing the app to slow down over time.

why not use the Virtual-scrolling of @angular/cdk? I know there're a poor documentation in the material page (really it's not of material else cdk)
